# Ошибка при запуске Ubuntu 18.04 "Failed to blank crtc!"

Tags: ubuntu, boot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед последним выключением ноутбука высветилось окно с надписью наподобие *"Установить обновления?".*
Принял это предложение, теперь, при попытке включения ноутбука выдаётся ошибка:

> "invalid threshold interrupt offset", "failed to blank crtc!"

и пр.
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ну а `systemctl reboot` не возвращает комп к жизни?

Comment: Нет, при запуске в recovery mode появляется recovery menu с функциями resume, clean, dpkg, может быть это как-то поможет?

Comment: А кстати. Если всё-таки дёрнуть журналцтл - чё вывалится?